# Python - Buttons with process

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a button where it will start a program. So first, a button called 'Run' will appear, subsequently after 3 seconds it should come up with a new button that says 'Stop'.

The reason I want it that way. That it's because I have tried and add two buttons on an interface panel, but the problem is then, every time I run an application, the interface freezes, so it was not possible to 'Stop' the program. So, I was wondering if it would be possible to do something like that?

What I've done:

```
from tkinter import *

tkWindow = Tk()
tkWindow.geometry('150x50')
tkWindow.title('Tkinter Example')

print("Tkinter button is appearing...")
def Action():
    from Launch import Launch
    run = Launch()
    run

def Off():
    import sys
    sys.exit()

button = Button(tkWindow,
                text='Start',
                command=Action)


button1 = Button(tkWindow,
                text='Stop',
                command=Off)
button.pack()
button1.pack()
tkWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Start `Launch` in a new thread. Add `from threading import Thread` and then instead of `run = Launch()` use: `Thread(target=Launch, daemon=True).start()`

Comment: I don't know how much You know but using `run = Launch()` and then just referencing `run` like You do is quite pointless. in this specific case You seem to be fine with just `Launch()` without instantiating it and that last `run` is pointless anyways, just use the solution above

Comment: Still happens, I am not able to press on 'Stop' once clicked on 'Start', it freezes the button panel.

Comment: @Matiiss, I did. But that doesn't effect or makes any change to my problem.

Comment: please provide the current code then, show how You applied the suggestions. [edit] this post. also about suggestions: no point of using `sys.exit()` when You can just use `exit()` (which also means that nothing has to be imported for that), and usually file names are also `snake_case` as well as per PEP8 function and variable names are `snake_case`, whereas class names are `CapitalCase`(which You have done already)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
from Launch import Launch

tkWindow = Tk()
tkWindow.geometry('150x50')
tkWindow.title('Tkinter Example')

print("Tkinter button is appearing...")
def Action():
    thread = Thread(target=Launch, daemon=True)
    thread.start()
    # If you want to disable the button use:
    # button.config(state="disabled")

button = Button(tkWindow,
                text='Start',
                command=Action)

# Here I am going to use the built-in `exit` function as per @Matiiss' suggestion
button1 = Button(tkWindow,
                text='Stop',
                command=exit)
button.pack()
button1.pack()
tkWindow.mainloop()
```

It starts a new thread when the `"Start"` button is pressed. That new thread calls `Launch`, leaving the main thread for `tkinter`. Please make sure that there isn't any references to your main GUI in your `Launch` function.